# NPM crashed Issue React

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to install and run react project , on the same machine where my angular application are running properly. when i run npm start it is giving me following error stack:-

```
  0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.20.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~prestart: myreactapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~start: myreactapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\ReactProject\myreactapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin;C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\ReactProject\myreactapp
10 silly lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myreactapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: myreactapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid myreactapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\ReactProject\myreactapp
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.20.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error myreactapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myreactapp@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My node version is v10x.
and npm is 6.
I tried every solution from the web like by cleaning cache and installing node modules again
can any one suggest me any workaround for above problem

Comment: please update your npm. It will be resolve your error.

Answer (score 0):

At first try with

```
npm cache clean
```

Then uninstall nodejs using revouninstaller then reinstall new version hope your problem will solved .